# Is there a condensed treasure generation table?

Tags: treasure, rolemaster, random-generation

The **Rolemaster FRP Treasure Companion** (ICE 5811) provides a pretty good treasure generation method, but I was wondering if there is an alternate condensed version with similar results. Maybe in another Companion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rolemaster Companion 3 (ICE 1700) page 36 Has what you want I believe.

A single table classified by level of the monster defeated.
The table has rows for bp, sp, gp, pp and mp, gems and jewels, combat items, 1 use items, modest, potent, most potent and artifacts with a % chance and number for each row. This isn't the same as the base C&T charts but it's quick and easy and all on the same page.